# Cannot find in scope in swift in DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: swift

I have this code in SWift:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

func whatever() async -> Int{
    return 2;
}

func test(){
    Task.init{
        var testing:Int = 0
        do {
            testing = try await whatever()
        }
        catch {
            print("some error happened")
        }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("from dispa")
        if(testing == 0){
            print("testing was never set")
        }
    }
}

test()
```

It is a playground and upon running it, I get `Cannot find 'testing' in scope` in the if statement in the `DispatchQueue`

What am I doing wrong? Moving the code within the Task.init throws a different error: `Reference to captured var 'testing' in concurrently-executing code`

Comment: I’m pretty confident you have a foundational misunderstanding of the Swift concurrency system, but I don’t know what you’re trying to achieve here, so it’s hard to point you in the right direction. Could you edit your question to provide more context?

Comment: This might help for starters: https://swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-role-tasks-play-in-swift-concurrency/

Comment: @mpora Did my response answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `testing` is declared inside the `Task.init` scope right now, meaning the `DispatchQueue` closure has no access to it. To use it in both closures, you must move it to a scope in which both closures have access to it (ie a shared parent scope).

Once you've done that, I'll say it's a little unclear on what exactly you want happening here, but I'm guessing this is the result you are looking for. Note that you should be careful about mixing `Task`s and `DispatchQueue`s -- they are different paradigms and do not necessarily lead to the results that you think they would.

```
var testing = 0

func whatever() async throws -> Int {
    return 2 //note that nothing async or throwing is actually happening here
}

func test(){
    Task {
        do {
            testing = try await whatever()
        }
        catch {
            print("some error happened")
        }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("from dispatch")
        if testing == 0 {
            print("testing was never set")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There’s no synchronization between the dispatch queue and that task, so mostly likely that dispatched work item will run before `testing` was ever set.

Comment: Right (thus my note about lack of clarity of original intention). In a playground, it executes the `Task` and then the `DispatchQueue` item. I'm assuming this is because `test()` is run on the main thread, so `Task` never splits off to a new run loop (and `whatever` never actually `awaits` anything), and then the `DispatchQueue` runs, as we'd expect, on the new loop. But, I don't have proof of that.